# Google datastore - querying on key values

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a EntityKind SuggestedInterest. 
When I populate that with a key "GrpId" and property "suggestedint".

Now, I need the "suggestedint" value for a requested "GrpId"

So, I write the query as:

```
String findSuggestedInterest(String grpId)
{
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Filter filter = new FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY,FilterOperator.EQUAL,grpId);
    Query q0 = new Query("SuggestedInterest").setFilter(filter);
    PreparedQuery pq0 = datastore.prepare(q0);
    Entity result = pq0.asSingleEntity();
    return result.getProperty("suggestedint").toString();       
}
```

When I execute this code I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: __key__ filter value must be a Key
```

The developer docs told to use Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY to query on keys, but I guess I misunderstood. What is the correct way to query on key ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should pass it a `Key` instead of `String`:

```
Key grpKey = KeyFactory.createKey("SuggestedInterest", grpId)
```

then use it:

```
 Filter filter = 
    new FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY,FilterOperator.EQUAL,grpKey);
```

Comment: is this work for import com.google.cloud.datastore.StructuredQuery.Builder;? I found confusion with old query, and I tried no help.. even for this https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities

Comment: even for this https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities

also this [The Example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/datastore/src/test/java/com/google/datastore/snippets/ConceptsTest.java)

and this [Key Filters](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#key_filters)