# Objectify query filter by List of keys that have a parent

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I would like to create an Api method via Google App Engine (Objectify) that returns a CollectionResponse of the posts of the people that I am following, sorted by date descending.

I have an Entity `Post` and Entity `Profile` both of which have `Long id` as their key.

The`Post` Entity has the following property specifying it has a Parent:

```
@Parent
private Key<Profile> profileKey;
```

The `Profile` Entity has the following property storing a `List` of `id`'s of the people the profile is following:

```
// Ids of the profiles this person follows
private List<Long> following = new ArrayList<>(0);
```

I was thinking then, I could do something like this:

```
    List<Long> idsProfile = profile.getFollowing();

    Query<Goal> query = ofy().load().type(Post.class)
                    .order("-createdDate") 
                    .filterKey("in", idsProfile) 
                    .limit(Constants.DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT);

            if (cursor != null) {
                query = query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursor));
            }

            QueryResultIterator<Goal> queryIterator = query.iterator();
            List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<Post>(Constants.DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT);
            while (queryIterator.hasNext()) {
                postList.add(queryIterator.next());
            }

            return CollectionResponse.<Post>builder().setItems(postList).setNextPageToken(queryIterator.getCursor().toWebSafeString()).build();
```

What I am doing here is getting a `List` of all the `id`'s of `Profile`'s that someone is following and trying to query and filter on that `List` to only return the `Post`'s by those users.

But I am getting this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: __key__ filter value must be a Key"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: __key__ filter value must be a Key"
 }
}
```

I've been trying different things within the `.filterKey("in", idsProfile)` bit but can't seem to get it to work.

Could someone help me with that part to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can use an `IN` filter for filterKeys. Also in regard to the usage of `IN` in a cursor query the documentation says *Because the NOT_EQUAL and IN operators are implemented with multiple queries, queries that use them do not support cursors, nor do composite queries constructed with the CompositeFilterOperator.or method.* (Source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Limitations_of_cursors)

Comment: @konqi Damn that sucks. You might be right - I won't be able to use a cursor potentially.

Comment: Try what suggested in this answer, it helped me [link to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13673542/1095610)