# Search based on doc id in a structured query

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, zapier

I have stored data in Firestore and I need to search for a particular document whose documentid is test using the document id. I am using Zapier which requires the query to be in `json`(structured query). This is what I tried, but keeps throwing an error:

```json
    {
     "where": 
     {
        "fieldFilter": {
           "field": _id,
        },
        "op": "EQUAL",
        "value": {
            "stringValue": "test"
        }
      }
    }
```

**Updated:**

Looks the json format is correct. Checked using the [Json validation](https://jsonlint.com/)

```json
    {
    "from": [{
        "collectionId": "practices"
    }],
    "where": {
        "fieldFilter": {
            "field": {
                "fieldPath": "__name__"
            },
            "op": "EQUAL",
            "value": {
                "stringValue": "{{116914021__output}}"
            }
        }
     }
    }
```

It's throwing this error,

```json
    "error": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "__key__ filter value must be a Key",
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
      }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google datastore - querying on key values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673180/google-datastore-querying-on-key-values)

Comment: Some of the fields isn't correctly set. Did you try to add manually a file and do a get first to see the exact structure? If not, could you provide more information about your Collection structure to try to see what fails?